# How can I set the spacing between input elements in CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: How can I make the Email and Password fields separated by the exact height of their icons?]
How can I make the Email and Password fields separated by the exact height of their icons? I tried using line-height but it only seems to work on text.

Of course I could simply look at the height of the icon in Firefox's Web Inspector and then say margin-bottom: xx px, but is that really the best way to do it?

My code looks like this:

```
            <form class="signup-field">
            <h1>Enter your email to start.</h1>
            <h2>Choose a strong password.</h2>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="input-group t-c-submit">
                <input type="checkbox">I agree to the terms and conditions.
                <button type="button" class="button">Get Started</button>
            </div>
            </form>
```

and my CSS looks like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "simple-line";
src: url("simple-line-icons-24.woff") format('woff');
}
.container {
    max-width: 880px;
}
.signup {
    background-color: #48b7d6;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Montserrat;
}
.signup h1 {
    font-size: 3.2em;
}
.signup h2 {
    font-size: 1.188em;
}
.signup-field input {
    background: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #dce3e7;
    margin: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}
.signup-field input::placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}
.signup-field button {
    float:right;
    font-size: 1.188em;
    background: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dce3e7;
    margin: 12px;
    min-width: 140px
}
.signup-field button:hover {
    background-color: #2fa1ba;
}

.signup-field .input-group-addon {
    font-family: simple-line;
    font-size: 1.188em;
    border: 1px solid #dce3e7;
    background: none;

    border-radius: 0;
    color: #fff;
}
/* Bootstrap overrides (also the above 3 lines) */
.input-group {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 200%;
}
```

Comment: A demo would be helpful. Could you set one up on CodePen?

Comment: Here you go: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZqqYK

Comment: I think the most accurate way to solve this problem is to do what you described: "...simply look at the height of the icon in Firefox's Web Inspector and then say margin-bottom: xx px...

Comment: You're missing the `form-group` divs your `input-group` divs should be in: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation Scroll down to the "with optional icons" section.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, I made another codepen with more code:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpNmaV
Thanks for pointing out the form-group. I'll take a look into it but I guess it doesn't really solve this question.